# Intro to Ruby: First Application

Tags: ruby

Anyone know why even though I enter in "Raphael" I still get the you are not the owner output?

```
print "Who are you:"
name = gets().capitalize
if (name != "Raphael") then
  print "You are not the owner of Genesis"
else
  puts ("Oh, hello #{name}...")
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gets()` includes the newline character you entered when pressing Enter.
Try using `gets.capitalize.chomp`.

If you want to know more about `chomp()`: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Check out my first complete applicaiton.

Comment: print "Who are you:"
name = gets().capitalize.chomp

print "Ah...so your name is #{name}\n"
 if (name != "Raphael") then
  print "You are not the owner of Genesis"
 else
  puts ("Welcome Back #{name}...")
 end